# Error While Fetching Data From Google Analytics API from R

Tags: r, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am able to receive Data from MCF API using RGA library.Sharing the Query:

```
temp_data <- get_mcf(profileId = "xxxxxxxxx", start.date = "2017-01-09",
     end.date = "2017-01-31", metrics = "mcf:totalConversions",
     dimensions = "mcf:sourceMediumPath", sort = NULL,
     filters = "mcf:conversionType==Transaction",
     samplingLevel = NULL,start.index=1,max.results = 100000)
```

The above query fetches me 14836 rows of data. When i'm trying to increase the data range I am getting this error.
Error: Server error: (500) Internal Server Error
Response too large: Internal Error

Is there any workaround ??

Comment: Increasing data range or date range?

Comment: Increasing the date range increases the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation for the MCF API you will find that the valid values for Max-results is a number between 1000 and 10000.

> [max-results](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/reference#maxResults)
>
> max-results=100 Optional. Maximum number of rows to include in this
>   response. You can use this in combination with start-index to retrieve
>   a subset of elements, or use it alone to restrict the number of
>   returned elements, starting with the first. If max-results is not
>   supplied, the query returns the default maximum of 1000 rows.
>
> The Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API returns a maximum of 10,000
>   rows per request, no matter how many you ask for. It can also return
>   fewer rows than requested, if there aren't as many dimension segments
>   as you expect. For instance, there are fewer than 300 possible values
>   for mcf:medium, so when segmenting only by medium, you can't get more
>   than 300 rows, even if you set max-results to a higher value.

You should be using [nextLink](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/reference#response_format) in order to retrieve the next set of data if you have more then 10000 rows in your response.

**Update**:  Out of curiosity I contacted Google Analytics API team.  I thought it strange that you are getting more rows back then you should be based upon the documentation.   This is the response I got back

> To me it sounds like the developer needs to just shorten the date
>   range to not get 500 server timeout. I don't know how he knows how
>   many row's a query will return when he is getting a 500 response so I
>   think there is a bit of confusion in his question still. As far as I
>   know we have not changed the number of rows allowed in the response,
>   but we still need to construct the full response on our side and sort,
>   so if the number of rows is large and the CPU usage on the server is
>   heavy during his request he will easily get a 500 timeout error.
>
> That being said I have asked the Backend team if anything has changed about the 10k limit recently..
>   - google dev who shall not be named -

Comment: Thanks for your response..
As mentioned above, this code fetches me 14386 rows of data in one go using batch processing. Therefore i don't think it is an issue of limits per request that can be pulled from API

Comment: Check update I thought it was strange the number of rows you said you are receiving so I contacted google here is the response.

Comment: Yes i understand we have a limit of 10000 rows but in this case i have used a feature called auto-pagination included in the RGA package.Auto-pagination to return more than 10,000 rows of the results by combining multiple data requests. I have refered this document for thesame : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGA/RGA.pdf.

Comment: The server will still have to process the full result set before returning it to you.   If you continue to see the error message you may want to try and break it up into chunks were the date range is less.

Comment: Yes exactly. Now we are on the same page. I was hoping for some workaround for this.

Comment: There isn't one that I know of I have been ripping data out of Google Analytics for four years now we have several customers were we have to take it in chunks of 1 day at a time.   As developers we will always be limited to the speed that the host site wants us to have the data.    I have been working with Google to get the rows increased but as my contact mentioned that's going to require more power on their servers not an easy think when you think of how many servers they have.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error you may chunk your request by days to get all data at one request. Like this:

```
start_date <- "some_date"
end_date <- "some_date"

dates <- seq(as.Date(start_date), as.Date(end_date), by = 'day') #making vector of dates

mcf_data <- lapply(seq_along(dates), function(x){
  get_mcf(profileId = ,
          start.date = dates[x], end.date = dates[x], 
          metrics = "", 
          dimensions = "",
          samplingLevel = "")
})

mcf_data <- data.table::rbindlist(mcf_data) #binding to a dataframe
```